# Stored procedure with Entity Framework get only one column

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I want to get specific column of the table but I get this error

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'NewsDatabaseModel.News'. A member of the type, 'NewsSubject', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I don't want to use stored procedure via the model I just want to call it.

Here is my code

```
var NewsList = db.Database.SqlQuery<News_Application.News>("[dbo].[GetAllNews]").ToList();
return View("NewsList");
```

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllNews
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NewsId, NewsTitle  
    FROM News
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `News_Application.News` class must have the same named properties as the returned select from your stored procedure, and all properties must exist in the select sentence.

Since you only want a single column, create a ViewModel class and bind your procedure to it like this:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
     public int NewsId { get; set;}
     public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
}
```

and bind your procedure

```
var NewsList = db.Database.SqlQuery<NewsViewModel>("[dbo].[GetAllNews]").ToList();
```

[EDIT]

For returning an anonymous object, do like this:

```
var NewsList = db.Database.SqlQuery<NewsViewModel>("[dbo].[GetAllNews]").Select(x => new { x.NewsId, x.NewsTitle }).ToList();
```

This will return an object that has no class and the properties you need.

Either way, I believe you should reconsider your design. There shouldn't be the need to use a stored procedure for executing such a simple query.
Lets suppose your entity's name is `News`.

This would suffice:

```
var NewsList = db.News.Select(x => new { x.NewsId, x.NewsTitle }).ToList();
```

I'll recommend this website for getting you up to speed with entity framework: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx

Comment: Thank you victor for reply ... acutally my entity looks like this public class News { public int NewsId { get; set;} public string NewsTitle { get; set; } public string Subject { get; set; } public string Date { get; set; } } I only need to get NewsID and NewsTitle , that's why i wrote SELECT NewsId, NewsTitle FROM News

Comment: That's your problem: you have two properties that your select isn't retrieving. (Subject and Date). Thats the reason for your error. You have to do as I suggested, or use an anonymous object

Comment: Thank you so  much Victor for helping, can you please give me a simple example of anonymous object